# Move Item fails with Bad Request error when i use special chars in parentReference.path

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Here is the request and response for move item.

Request +1

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!2jIVYv-TmkuIJKAhTCyu6WeVZIBaVEpEmt_D06E9j2ZNSSz7vQgARJphpkDG4raQ/root:/test/text.xml:

{"parentReference":{"path":"/drive/root:/@$%^&()_++={}[];1233Asaa"}}

Response: {"error": {
"code": "invalidRequest","message": "Invalid request","innerError": {"date": "2020-10-09T14:42:18","request-id": "b337c007-2fb5-493b-934f-e1b7dee37222","client-request-id": "989068eb-5115-4dc2-4bc9-80b918a6b5c3" } }}

As we are able to create folder using the above special characters, So expecting it to work when we use them in Move Item. Can you please help us understand what special character is causing issue and What all things we need to take care of when we do copy and Move?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the service - we're working on a fix, but in the meantime can you use `id` instead of `path`? This may require another round-trip to resolve the `id` value, but it'll allow the scenario to work until the fix is deployed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you update here once this issue fixed.?